# Requirejs not passing backbone model id

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

Since I have switched to require.js for my app using backbone it appears that my model is no longer getting or adding my ID to the URL like it use to.

```
  var campaign = new CampaginModel({id: options.id});
```

when I console out the model the url is `/api/campaign/` when before it was `/api/campaign/1/`

What I'm I doing wrong?

**View:**

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'views/RewardView',
  'views/FriendRewardView',
  'models/CampaginModel',
  'text!templates/backbone/portal/campaignTemplate.html'
], function($, _, Backbone, rewardView, friendRewardView, CampaginModel, campaignTemplate){



   var CampaginView = Backbone.View.extend({
       el: '#campaign-panel',

        // View constructor
        initialize: function() {
            // Storing the View context
            self = this;
        },


        render: function(options) {
            if(options.id){


                var campaign = new CampaginModel({id: options.id});

                console.log('model', campaign)

                campaign.fetch({
                    success: function(campaign){
                        // We can only get the reward when the campaign reward url is returned.

                        var rewardview = new RewardView();
                        rewardview.render({reward_url: campaign.get('participant_reward')});


                        var friendview = new FriendRewardView();
                        friendview.render({reward_url: campaign.get('friend_reward')});


                        var template = _.template(campaignTemplate, {campaign: campaign});
                        this.$el.html(template);


                    }// end success

                    ,

                    error: function (model, response) {
                      console.log('error', model, response);
                    }// end of error

                }); // end fetch
            }// end if option.id
        } // end render function
    }); // end campagin view


  return CampaginView;

});
```

**Model:**

```
define([
  'underscore',
  'backbone'
], function(_, Backbone) {

    var CampaginModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
       urlRoot: '/api/v1/campaign/'
    });

  return CampaginModel;

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a require.js issue. You are defining urlRoot and therefore "overwriting" the default [URL](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url) in the form "[collection.url]/[id]", so you have to add the idAttribute to your definition:

```
var CampaginModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
   urlRoot: '/api/v1/campaign/',
   idAtttribute: 'id'
});
```

Cheers.

Comment: wow so helpful on this and my last few questions, again many thanks. If I defined collections will this work without idAtttribute?

Comment: Yes, it should, if the model is part of the collection its url would be that of "[collection.url]/[id]" as long as you are not defining an urlRoot.